# Get closest value in array to variable value

Tags: dart

I have an array of `int` I'd like to create a function which retrieves from this array the closest value to `randomInt`

```dart
final myArray = [10 , 20, 14, 15, 18, 24];

final int randomInt = 21;

getClosestValueInArray(myArray, randomInt); // should return 20


int getClosestValueInArray(List<int> array, int value) {


}
```

Comment: What have you tried yourself?

Comment: I've tried to find an existing method on dart lists but haven't found any

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could loop through the array and check closeness for each element. E.g. in pseudo-code:

```
closest = myArray[0]
best_closeness = abs(myArray[0] - randomInt)
for (element in myArray) {
  closeness = abs(element - randomInt)
  if (closeness < best_closeness) {
    closest = element
    best_closeness = closeness
  }
}
return closest
```

And in Dart (added by @julemand101)

```dart
int getClosestValueInArray(List<int> array, int value) {
  int closest = array.first;
  int best_closeness = (closest - value).abs();

  for (int element in array.skip(1)) {
    int closeness = (element - value).abs();

    if (closeness < best_closeness) {
      closest = element;
      best_closeness = closeness;
    }
  }

  return closest;
}
```

Comment: Added your solution written in Dart. You are welcome to remove it or edit it if you don't like it. :)

Comment: @Sunshine I could also add `int getClosestValueInArray(List<int> array, int value) => array.reduce((a, b) => (value - a).abs() < (value - b).abs() ? a : b);` as a solution if you just want a short version. It does, however, end up doing recalculation of numbers it have already calculated its closeness on before. But since `(value - number).abs()` should be cheap, it might not be a problem for most use cases.

Comment: ok thanks a lot @julemand101 what should I do if I'd like to return the **`index`** in the array where element is closest to randomIntValue instead of the value from the array ?

Comment: @Sunshine Well, it would have been nice if this requirement was part of the question. I don't really want to keep adding to an answer that are not even mine. But you can just change `closest` to keep track of the index, instead of having the value.

Comment: @julemand101 ok I'll try to open a new question thanks a lot

Comment: @Sunshine Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/246775/discussion-between-julemand101-and-sunshine).

Answer (score 0):

One option is to put these elements in a `TreeSet` and then use `ts.floor(randomInt)` and `ts.ceil(randomInt)` to check what the nearest elements to `randomInt` is, and pick the one with the smallest absolute difference to `randomInt`.

Another option is to put these values in a hashset and then search for `randomInt - 1`, `randomInt + 1`, `randomInt - 2` and so on. This again has benefits and drawbacks compared to the previous approach.

There are many other ways.

Comment: Interesting would you mind sharing code ? : )

Comment: Sorry didn't know you were looking for Dart code.